# AWS Amplify Authentication Google Sign In

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I'm using AWS Amplify Studio to add authentication to my amplify project.

I already have my Web Client ID and Web Client Secret but I'm missing "Sign-in & sign-out redirect URLs." I'm unsure what "Sign-in & sign-out redirect URLs" refers to, could someone explain what this would mean for a mobile application?

In a web development perspective it looks like that would be the project's homepage url.